# How to show UIColor picker in Swift playgroundbook code completion?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I would like my students to be able to choose colors in their Swift code on the iPad with the cool UIColor picker box that Apple shows in the completion bar. While I can use //#-code-completion(everything, show) and others documented by Apple to show it, it's among a bunch of other stuff as well that will confuse the beginning students. I want to show *only* the UIColor picker and my identifiers. How can I do this?

```
//#-code-completion(everything, hide)
//#-code-completion(identifier, show, moveForward(), turnLeft(), moveBackward(), turnRight())
//
// the following attempt to show the UIColor picker doesn't work
//
//#-code-completion(identifier, show, UIColor.init(red:, green:, blue:, alpha:))
//#-hidden-code
setup()
//#-end-hidden-code
import UIKit
//#-editable-code Tap to enter code
//#-end-editable-code
//#-hidden-code
exitProgram()
```